# how can i append options to all select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#selectid-1').append(<option value='1'> options</option>) 
// it will add options to select element with id id=selectid-1.<br>
```

Is there any way to write something like this `$('.xyz').append(<option value='1'> options</option>)` to append options to all select element?
If no, then how can I append options to all `<select>` elements?

```html
< li class="x y z" id="id-1">
  <select id="selectid-1">
  <option value></option>
  </select>
</li>
.
.
.
.
<li class="x y z" id="id-n">
  <select id="selectid-n">
  <option value></option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Comment: You can try like this : `$(".xyz select").append(options)`

Comment: Yes you can. just add a class name to your select like <select class="xyz"></select>

Comment: $(".x y z select").append(options); but not working

Comment: Try : `$(".x select").append(options)`

Comment: you have 3 classes for every li element (x y z), so you must use only 1 class to select, such as `$(".x select").append(result.options)` or `$(".y select").append(result.options)` or `$(".z select").append(result.options)`

Answer (score 1):

If you target *all* the `select` elements the option will be applied to all of them.

```js
$('select').append("<option value='1'>options</option>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="x y z" id="id-1">
    <select id="selectid-1">
      <option value></option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li class="x y z" id="id-n">
    <select id="selectid-n">
      <option value></option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If, you don't want to target every select element on the entire page, you could give the ones you're interested in a common class and target them that way

```js
$('select.add-options').append("<option value='1'>options</option>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="x y z" id="id-1">
    <select id="selectid-1" class="add-options">
      <option value></option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li class="x y z" id="id-n">
    <select id="selectid-n" class="add-options">
      <option value></option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>

<select>
   <option>this one wont get a new option</option>
</select>
```